# How to set an object to enable from another activity/fragment?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have an autocomplete textview. I disabled it and i want it to be enabled after a button is click which is from another activity. How will i do that?

Comment: Use one boolean static variable in Activity A, initially set it to false, and change its value to true when a button is pressed in other Activity B. on returning to Activity A , check value of static boolean variable and enable/Disable textview accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

if your activity doesn't destory you should make interface to aware activity to enable autocomplete textview

Answer (score 0):

When you are changing activity by Intent . add This.

```
intent.putExtra("isButtonEnable",true);
```

And get That in Other Activity onCreate like This.

```
if(getIntent.getExtras.getBoolean("isButtonEnable")){
yourTextView.setEnable(true);
}
else{
yourTextView.setEnable(false);
}
```

Same as you can do it in fragment also

Answer (score 0):

ActivityA

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(ActivitA.this, ActivitB.class);                     
 intent.putExtra("EditTextVisible", true);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Then in ActivityB in onCreate():

```
         if(getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EditTextVisible")) {
         editTextB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

first create a public method in your first activity where u want to manipulate the widget

```
public class methodEnable()
{
 //your code
}
```

Then in your other class create a object of ur first class

```
FirstClass f1=new FirstClass();
```

Now on Button Click:

```
f1. methodEnable();
```

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Make flag in your api-code and when second activity is closed - first activity will appear onResume function, where you can check you api and set enable TextView